# Loading external DLLs (e.g. stringio.so) in embedded Ruby interpreter

Tags: ruby, windows, dll, roo

I'm using the Ruby interpreter embedded in the game Dwarf Fortress (it ships with 1.8.x, but I've replaced the DLL with 1.9.3), and I'm trying to include the Roo library so I can work with spreadsheets.

```
puts(RUBY_DESCRIPTION)

def addDir(libdir)
    $LOAD_PATH.unshift(libdir) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(libdir)
end 

addDir('C:\dev\Ruby193\lib\ruby')
addDir('C:\dev\Ruby193\lib\ruby\1.9.1')
addDir('C:\dev\Ruby193\lib\ruby\1.9.1\i386-mingw32')
addDir('C:\dev\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\roo-2.1.1\lib')

require 'roo'

filename = "example.ods"
@spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(filename)
puts("Loaded " + filename + " with " + @spreadsheet.sheets.length.to_s + " sheets")
```

[image: Script running on command line]
[image: Script running in Dwarf Fortress' dfhack console]

Running from the command-line, everything is fine, but trying inside the embedded interpreter results in an 'incompatible library version' error.

I'm clearly missing something about the different environments here - can anyone tell me how I'd go about successfully loading these libraries (I gather that although they are extended .so they are in fact DLLs) in an interpreted environment?

Comment: could be a path issue?

Comment: Moving `stringio.so` results in the error becoming `cannot load such file - stringio`, so I'm reasonably confident it's being found.

Comment: hum... The `1.91` part of `Ruby193\lib\ruby\1.9.1'` is what concerns me. normally that would be the same as your ruby version, i.e. `1.9.3`, but this is a unique case and I'm not sure.

Comment: That had me surprised as well! That's how RubyInstaller left it and it works fine in the command-line.

Comment: Are you using dfhack? If so here is a relevant issue https://github.com/DFHack/dfhack/issues/271

Comment: That looks very relevant (and ashamed I didn't find it myself) - I'll investigate this - thanks

Comment: No worries! I always dig into github issues when I try to answer SO questions. Let me know if you find anything.

Comment: It looks to me like there are some `cpp` files. I know the DevKit's compiler toolchain we are using cause some `c++` library interoperability breakage between versions. I would suggest recompiling `dfhack` with the DevKit of the Ruby you are using. "Just in Case". Also just to clear things up, 1.9.1 introduced a ABI breaking change. Until there's another ABI change the files are stored that way. Recently they've released a `minor` version change when the ABI changes. *e.g. `2.2.0` `2.3.0`*